# Compressing many very small PNG's

Tags: compression, png

I have a directory containing approximately 32,000 very small PNGs. All the images are 224x224, single channel, single byte (ie. grayscale, 0-255.) They all have a pretty wide black border (and black regions closer to the object.) They are also all images of the same object, though at different orientations. Therefore many images are quite similar to one another. Here are two examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

According to tools like `du`, the file size for each of them is 4kb – I believe this is because the block size on my system is 4kb. I'm not sure how to estimate, but I would imagine that the actual data is smaller than 4kb.

First question: How can I estimate the amount of storage actually needed to store this image? I tried reading the bytes directly into memory, but of course this also takes all the bytes from the block, and I'm not sure which are just garbage bytes.

I would like to compress all these images together. I know that PNGs can't be compressed further, but I believe that if I can compress all the images into a single solid compression, I can benefit from:

1. Minimal extra padding – instead of a separate file (with minimum block size) for each image, all images will stored sequentially with no padding
2. Better PNG compression – by sharing the dictionaries (I think this is the correct term) across many images with similar characteristics, more efficient compression can be employed
3. The common areas of the image (the black borders) can be compressed across images

I've tried several compression algorithms (I think done correctly, with either `tar` or  the python library `py7zr`) but got very little compression:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 avic sinha 110M Jun 27 13:59 images.7z
-rw-r--r-- 1 avic sinha 137M Jun 27 12:08 images.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 avic sinha 137M Jun 27 12:51 images.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 avic sinha 137M Jun 27 12:50 images.tar.xz
```

Each image is 4kb, and there are 32768 images, which means uncompressed the total size is 131.072 mb. The compressions above are either larger or slightly smaller (85% of original size.)

How might I compress further?

Comment: The examples you provided are not 4K. They are all over 8K. You can use `ls -l` to see the actual file sizes, which for those are 8846, 8754, and 8701 bytes.

Comment: You can first try [pngcrush](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmt/files/pngcrush/) to see if the individual images will compress further.

Comment: pngcrush reduced your examples by 9% to 13%.

Comment: Also the example PNG files have several informational chunks that may not be necessary: iCCP, eXIf, and iTXt. The iCCP chunk (a color profile) in each is 3332 bytes.